# Pass question mark url with Ajax load in a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, url

I have a simple Ajax-load function that loads another php file into a div '#content_box' via a form. The month and year parameters are determined by respectively #dm and #dy. The submit button has passed the id #ds.
I was wondering, what is the best way to pass these parameters to the browser url (i.e. how to obtain an url such as www.site.com/ddchart?dm=june&dy=2014&ds=Go )?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#df').submit(function(){
    var month_ddchart = $('#dm').val();
    var year_ddchart = $('#dy').val();
    source_ddchart = '/data/ddc-'+month_ddchart+'-'+year_ddchart+'-body.php';
    $('#content_box').load(source_ddchart);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question correctly but if your `form` is doing a `get` instead of a `post` then the results will be added onto the query string automatically when it's submitted..

Comment: I'm doing a method="GET" request, but the results aren't added onto the string